# C++ standard library Priority Queue

Tags: c++

Trying to do:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
            vector<int>* V = new std::vector<int>();
            
            V[0].push_back(1);
            V[0].push_back(2);
            V[1].push_back(3);
            V[1].push_back(4);
            V[2].push_back(5);
            
            priority_queue<int, vector<int>*, less<vector<int>*>> pq1;
            
            return 0;
}
```

Getting following error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/queue:425:22: error: type 'std::priority_queue\<int, std::vector\<int\> \*, std::less\<std::vector\<int\>\>\>::container_type' (aka 'std::vector\<int\> \*') cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
typedef typename container_type::value_type      value_type;
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers there?  You're only allocating one `vector`, so `V[1]` and `V[2]` are not defined.  The second type in a `priority_queue` needs to be a container, not a pointer to a container.

Comment: `priority_queue` is a container adapter, not a pointer adapter.

Comment: `new std::vector<int>()` creates one single vector, not an array of three vectors. What you seem to want is `std::array<std::vector<int>, 3> V;` instead.

Comment: *Priority* queue. The compiler doesn't accept mis-spellings, and neither will your employers or your customers. Not even your teachers I would hope. Precision please. It's a precise business.

Comment: As for the priority queue, what is its purpose? What is its relation to the array of vectors you have? What is the original and actual problem you're trying to solve with the array and queue?

Comment: Hard to give advice when the code you've written makes no sense, and you fail to explain what you are trying to achieve. Don't use pointers is the only advice I can give. But there seem to be multiple misunderstandings in your code, so that's just the first step.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize a priority queue from a vector then do it like this :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <queue>

//using namespace std; <== no don't do this.

int main()
{
    // useless new!
    //std::vector<int> V = new std::vector<int>();

    std::vector<int> V{1,9,2,8,3,7,4,5}; // this is how to initialize a vector
    std::priority_queue<int> pq{V.begin(),V.end()}; // initialize queue from vector data

    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        std::cout << pq.top() << " ";
        pq.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or beginning with C++23 with `std::from_range_t` tag type parameter to the priority _queue constructor.

Comment: @Sebastian Nice one

Comment: Thank you. As better description of my comment. One is/will be able to use `std::priority_queue pq{std::from_range, V};`. This was introduced with P1206 (https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1206r7.pdf), and is so far supported by MSVC >=19.34 and Clang >=17 (if compiled with `-stdlib=libc++`) - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23.

Comment: For libstdc++ support, see Jonathan Wakely working on it https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=111055